# Software to send messages to people on multiple chat channels

Tags: chat

I am very tired of trying to contact coworkers who do not respond to messages because they're all on different channels.

This hearkened me back to an earlier more disjointed time a little after AOL IMs when there were like 52 different messaging platforms on the internet, and if you wanted to talk to all of them without running all of them you could use a nice little multiplexer called Digsby and another one called Pigeon that would tap into all of those different protocols for you.

My hope is that I will be able to send the same message once to all of them.

(Hopefully they won't get mad...but maybe it will cause someone in leadership to determine they need to agree on a standard).

MS Teams, SMS, Email

I'd also like it to be a good secure program...maybe I need an API Library or something.

Comment: Gajim comes to mind, too. What OS should it run on? And what price is acceptable?

Comment: Please list all "channels" you want the software to cover. Thanks!